# Как устроено дерево моделей ESP8266?

Tags: esp8266

Я правильно понимаю, что **ESP8266** - это чип от производителя, а  от **ESP-01** до **ESP-12** - модули на основе этого чипа? Если нет, объясните, пожалуйста, как устроено дерево моделей **ESP8266**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Я правильно понимаю, что ESP8266 - это чип от производителя, а от
> ESP-01 до ESP-12 - модули на основе этого чипа?

**Да**. Просто разные корпуса и антенны

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ESP-32 - другая линейка чипов.

ESP-01 и ESP-01s различаются шелкографией. Бывают с 0.5М и 1М флешками

ESP-07 совпадат по пинам, внешняя антенна на версии S.

ESP-12 также разные антенны.

https://www.ret.hu/media/product/32391/612749/esp8266_series_modules_user_manual_v1.1.pdf

Также стоит обращать внимания на то что сейчас пихают флешки без поддержки qio в не зависимости от маркировки.